# Find out index of an iframe from parent

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is is possible for an iframe to find out its index amongst all other iframes in the parent iframe?
Assuming that cross-domain restrictions still apply, I was thinking of using postMessage but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

If the child is in the **same domain** you can access the parent, window.parent.

**In cross-domain**, you can establish a service to save the iframe positions on the parent and have the children read it.